# How to make a SQL query like this?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

Given 2 base tables, 1 table which stores the relation between them with a few extra attributes; taking a few extra attribute values as user input, based on that extracting relation from relation table.

This information has the ID of the main values (person and animal) not the names. I want to display the names on screen, like according to the input you gave the records which found are this person has this animal with him.

```
    select DISTINCT table0.person_name, table5.animal_name 
      from table1

 INNER JOIN table0, table5 
        on table1.person_id=table0.person_id
            and
        table1.animal_id=table5.animal_id

where table1.aa=input1 
       and table1.bb=input2 
       and table1.cc=input3 
       and table1.dd=input4
```

Comment: Those are the worst names I've ever seen.

Comment: Can you make it clearer what doesn't work at the moment? i.e. what is the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: 2 base tables, 1 table which stores the relation between them with a fex extra attributes

taking fex extra attributes value as user input, based on that extracting raletion from relation table.

this information has the id of the main values (person and animal) not the names

i want to display the names on screen

like

according to the input u gave the records which found are this person has this animal with him

thats it,

Comment: I suspect this question is too localised, and is not going to be of much help to future readers. I think it should therefore be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three errors.

- The `WHERE` clause should come after the `JOIN .. ON` clause, not before it.
- You cannot refer to columns in table5 because it doesn't appear in the FROM list.
- You shouldn't write `ON xxx AND ON yyy`. Just write `ON xxx AND yyy`.

Other points to consider:

- Are you sure that you meant FULL OUTER JOIN and not INNER JOIN?
- Why do you add the distinct? If a person owns two animals with the same name do you really want to return only one row?
- Where do the values `input1, ..., input4` come from?
- I think `table0` should be renamed to `person`, `table5` to `animal`, and table1 to `person_animal` to make it easier to understand the purpose of each table.

My best guess as to what you meant is this:

```
SELECT table0.person_name, table5.animal_name 
FROM table1 
JOIN table0 ON table1.person_id = table0.person_id
JOIN table5 ON table1.animal_id = table5.animal_id
WHERE table1.aa = input1 
  AND table1.bb = input2 
  AND table1.cc = input3 
  AND table1.dd = input4
```